# Convert a string into an image when it comes from whatsapi

Tags: python, image, numpy, whatsapp

I am currently playing around with the api here:

https://github.com/mukulhase/WebWhatsAPI

It is pretty basic and one is able to recieve messages, however when recieving an image, I get a very cryptic string.

For example this image:

[image]

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCABMAGQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAQQDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABgQFBwgAAwkBAv/EADsQAAIBAwMCBAMECAUFAAAAAAECAwQFEQAGEiExBxMiQQgUUTJhcYEJFSNCocHR8BaCkbHhFzNScvH/xAAbAQACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQIDBgAHAf/EADERAAIBAwICBgkFAAAAAAAAAAECAAMEEQUhEjEGEyJBgZEUFTJCYXGh0eFRU2Kx8P/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AnGio3rJDFETzwMEDp1+unuo31ZvDWazbZulK810uEvm25o6YO6STs0TEFmVeIEMXIFk9Jckt9kfewqX5i7qrEAP6eo/LP8dKfH3Ymzq+ih3DvK5C326C3SUSyRKPNaVpFeNV/exkOW446e499Be1w1YW7cjPLejdki0fTPezjw2lH/G+03WHd15uF5qovnqmvlWUmtSok5J6SrmMlVIIYEDAz1xjGIqlSRpDl+eCep9/fRJ4i1e27cnyFBf6uop6WoZYFqccxGM9OntyJ6ff74zqPn3IYzmmlIB+mjetSmoR5rKSMwyseJ0JX9tPIgToAD20zXGeL/tQycuvXp20krL+KlGapnY/fj+OkMVwpZZOKuOOMjOQc/noG6rK+yD7xjb0ym7TcoYtIXA9TdB7Y+mtM8bPKCzAKcAD646/114lzo8PHI2G5EKeuMZ/sa3uAeJ7jvnQQ5wokYj1Z5JIIPNDEAkcgpwT9Pyzot2jfTYt02m9A+Y1BW09QyjDMzIUOVDdGPTGD0OcHp00DW+WRgI2yfXge3tp+tlPI9dCQCMY9XbiwY/y03oVCFCiIrykCWJl07htK9Q1kpgtzeSZH8oocrxDHGDk56Yx1OvKCw3oNmS3TBeJ6NGR9O+entq0ex7fbr5sjbl5ipkzW2qkqCoA9JeFWIOeuRnHXroj/wAKUT9fJTP14DQra8yEoU5TML0WosOIVD9JU9Nq3wLj9XSJjpjGs1attq0uT6Ix/lX+ms1X6/8A4yQ6KJ+4fKQttG4pQ3BZGfiQuB0+/OfxzqIv0gO4bhdtm7TistdKqNV1STxK4RSxWMKWY4wAQ3vjuT20fK7ocoxU/UHGtdVfNnWKknuG9LFFeYljPydM8PmMagEMCjYPlMFD+s4A7kjRtzagv6QOY/SLuj+qmiy2bDYnn/vlOZm8dv1FtvFRb2oLlTimYRyfPx+XOrgAPzUdIzyDenJIBAJJGdOPhxtAXa6VdRVuDSUNM0j8hyVmJAUEnt7n/Los8XqmDdG9Ljc6WZpVlmY+c/25s/vt0XqfckZOMnvqRZdi7Y8PPCiee13KauvN0aiaeZgUVCIpJHjRD3XEsJDnr07Ly4iNG3Vq4yO+bqrcEUcDYmVz3FTxi6yxQ/YDEdB0HXSKnpkAMnzMakDI6Zx+Wl8wb5yQz9TknJHc6V01rgrI2ZMBz7Z9J/s6E4QznaMCxVBGOqHE4MiyE4wyjGl1u816dkZTlTn8RpTLaIqSqXz8HKAqFP49fw/LXisqFsAcWOegwMf2NVspDYMsDArmLFnEEgYDJLK+M464xp1luodSIV4tI+B16dR/z/DQ88iu3Xv0P+//ABp3oqLzoMkgOPUMH8v66KpsTkCA1FBIJly/0eu7txP4l7i23PeKl7TUWWa5SUbMTGKlKmnRJgD9luEjqSB19Oc8Ri+63KB8ftSRj2Oqb/Af4czWXw+3D4pVsJSousiWu2yNGVYU0bKZnRs4ZHkKr26NA2iGLxE3H86YvP5IHIHqPYf39NAVbJr6u5pn2cZi291Chpyq1XOG5YEtKa2IknDazUb7dud0uNsSrdo8ux+1n7tZpe1iyMVJEimq0qihlBwZEVXVJSxNI3fiSox3xoB8ZqaqvPhzXS0LlZ6VkqEKdDgEKSCDkY5k5+g0a3Klarnp4Gb0OTkDv2P88aeafZy3m3VFrqVHl1cEsDniOgdSCT/r/trZVHVBlp5vYk066VFG4IM53VFGIZebeorkE/fog31e942XaNopblap4aHjmKpmh6TtIiuMv2JCcAATyAA9iNKLzb6amuSw3UfLU1G4+aBBDHDDlGMD7XfuR2PXOjn4gvHi0bk8NbftOz3mitqXdIzcrNQh5fKig4CmMsuFUkkOwjHLivAn15wMxelupxz3nqAbrGVSM+Eq213MlQ7NByDE5P4/jp7p0qaOGGXkvrwWUd1/HTHBPbKbkWmZj2BCAj+J1uW7QocCo7nsVPXS1W4d2MaMNuyIuqZ3mqvOkkZlZAoBPYg61NIWZsjP89eOwmiEw98dxjrr5iTm/H3OuI3nzj2EUQRq4VieTdemc6mn4fvAbd3jjuWKx7ejgp6KNVkuVznGY6OAkjlxyDI2QQqKck4yVXLCGKA8GZwfsqR+Z6a6dfo79m0dq8HZd4iRzV32pkhdc+lI4HZVx07ks2e/QL9DqdSqKFE1Bz7vnAq7EMAO+T9ZdnWDw58PaLY+2oDBbLRRCng58ebnqWdyoALu5Z2IAyzE4GdVWpoEN3khJOFkZQff7WNXKusKz0xibJ5enA+/p/PQMvhbZEkeb5XLOSxJVToDT79bQv1m/FFWr6Y+pU0VGxwkxq2cnCwwoTnizDOPv1mjOh29BR04p46YcVJ76zVNS8R3LY5zqOm1KVNUyNhiQFa6ZZ6tS3H0dcHuf7/pqQrZQpC6ImeRxyI9sfT7tCNitMpmWU92HXHsPfUl2ugZRxYgMcFuvYfTTq/qjOAZlNHtiRkic+fi/wBh1m298XFKenkWhvNR+sYXHRT5321H3iQSdPYFT7jUGbh2P4eUW16WpWovTXoMi1YedXpiCvLKYQFWGQpUkj05DdeK9RPH/wAJYfE/Yk9JSUKSXa2rJU245Cs7FcNFkjoGwvuPUqZOAdUQq6XYc3hpW3fcVQJLyJ1WmoIIGTpGEiIlJwFYKpY45EnuVJI1fa9XeUxxcxt+flNjTrvbjhGTylb2ttlYhKOKdiOpLgYH9/jpRDRQ0zgLCVyQMccaJTX2ZJZY4YI4y/biCAPu/wDum+9SQAoyOBjuBqNS1RVLhh4RktwzMFIPjG64OFQJBGVIOcAds61KxGCD176S1FcHqHIXKucdNetOfmVTuMkaDZgTtCAhA3jhTy8TxOPV3J11H/R6bjjrvAcWx5lLWu61UIUMCVVuMgOPbJdu/wBDrltCI8EsT0GT/rq5nwC+IbWik3dtKOpzVvDBdaSl5481YyUmCDsWw6HA6kL746RrJ1tAoOe39wO4wuHPIfadEamsQsoxkdCcHtpSJYsYCgg4P2tV8bxtjZ0crIhTJIYHJ+vsMa+oPHZKivSjWNjyIH72Ac/j30AdKuT7sC9bWQGetHnJ8aeHkfWo+7Os0A0G5/m6ZZnkYE/+LHGs0KbOoDgiWjUaBGzCDW3aikaJCWRvUMge4x/HHXRBdrxebfZKut2vaKa8XGNOcFDPWfKLOQeq+bwfieIbjlcFuIJUEutftr7guiiKH5glW6dck/axqTNvXu4SyIrSABWwMD8P660V1ZEEtmYvTtUFMhCsHx4hfF1PuW10P/Qjb9LZ5YRFW1TXyGYQ1DjiJARKriCNgXfETyMpARS2dVx+Knw3gqr/AG3c+76i0eF77lhnqKtJoZ62OaqVaWTAWk83EpNVLE7YVGeikkGRMjNeOG5VUdNPMGHKFCy/QnBPX/QapD8cG4Ljumx7arrmyB4K64UyLGCFCgwjPUk56/X2GgqCupJU4mwtbxK9ZKZXGZAtH4X+DC1VLU3j4nKakt9a5HODZlwnqKUZJQzxlkTPEYbynkwxAHJcuGeu2J4LxV9bCfiRiqqSmtVTVw1NPtCuzNWRCEx0vCV04iXnNiUkKoh9QHMYBpHZ6JYnOQpbB9/Sen++t2zd27g2JuKj3dtSvFDdqAs9NUeTHL5bMjISFkVlJ4scZHTuOoB1A55ZmhKcJ2jvNaPCurW53S3eJkNnhg+Z/V1rraeetrKgJRiaB3mjhjiRJJg1OT1KMyOVaPk4O67w6+HahuCVcfxI1FxpP1pTxGGPZ9XTyfJGqp45pRIzMOSQPUSgFBy8kDAZwgHaP4gvFi20ktLS7hovImSWNoZbJQSxhZJqmZwqvCQoL11UfTjAlKjCgAA95q5LhO1fNHTxyVDvMyU8CQRKzHJCRxgIi9eiqAoGAAAMa+gEd8ieYBkz2nw9+HCoguNNW/E3WwVEdxigoqtdkVUkU1GaSOR5ZIPMDRsKh3hwJHP7Bm4lXVgjsdR4T7dvVXbLR4g7mgrKa8w09t3alrRKN6FvJD1D0HM1Eflk1DBlmaQhYgIgWYrEMA8sK6ZBJ69e/b+ulCMWdlJ/f4/w1YnEu4JlNRQeyRkS8e2fHXYO6/DpBvTdG3aXfFHRgQy0VhrkaqkWnQiGZwxilZpHcPUYiIMPRGVg2pR2JtO373giue0dy2fcM0UfKqjoHkEsDAAn9jOqSAEH0+k+46kHXOS2zSrUBQ5wev5gD+uj+wXi5USLJS1TRNFwKkY7hjjv/wCo07taRqUzwuQfjuPLY/WZjUdNt6x9gA/Db8fSdMqChrbbT/K1FOY5AxJWUFGX7iCNZqmVs+IjxtpbfT08XiTeSiRqB5kwkbt7swJP5nWa46Hcv2sr5n7RWKSJ2Qx2+An/2Q==
```

Will look like this string pictured above

My attempt was to convert the string into a byte representation:

```
 msg = message[u'message']
 by = str.encode(msg)
```

After that I would convert it into a numpy array to reshape it into the image dimensiosn (e.g. 480x368 pixel).

However, there are two main problems:

When converting it into a numpy array it will get depicted as `dtype='|S4876'` which is not convertible into a numeric representation. So how can I restore the image out of the chunk I am presented? Is it possible without knowing the image dimension?

Will produce the follwing output:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image data is encoded in Base64 format.
You can try to put your "cryptic string" [here](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and the result you get is exactly that image

[base64ToImage codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)